# All combinations in Lottery game (6\40 + 1\7)

Tags: python

I have homework with a lottery game with 6 digits between 1-40 and additional digit with 1-7.

Possible examples include: "22,40,3,10,23,24,7"  "24,30,333,11,22,24,6".

So the seventh position should be from 1 to 7.

I'm programming Python code to put all the combinations in a txt file with low processing time.

I've picked up this code from the previous questions asked here in stack overflow:

```
from itertools import combinations
f = open('combinations.txt', 'w')
for comb in combinations(range(1,50), 6):
    f.write(str(comb))
    f.write('\n')
f.close()
```

How can I edit this code to get a 7th digit with range 1-7?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Comment: Specifically: "Make a good faith attempt to solve the problem yourself first." AND "Never use code you don't understand."

Comment: @Mind5 What kind of lottery is this? If a number is drawn, can you get the same number again and does order matter? For example, is `1, 2, 2` the same as `2, 2, 1`?